# Failed to display image in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have angular 6 application, wherein Images are coming from API to display like below :

```
 <img class="news-image" src="{{ news.pictureUrl }}" alt="News headline image">
```

However, In the customer environment we have different images coming togather and pops out of container ( may be width issue, also since we dont have access to customer environment, we can not reproduce at our end).

So to test it, I would like to replace the images to refer my local computer instead of server path, However it does not show image, Please see below code which I tried for the same in the browser HTML.

```
<img class="news-image" src="file://c://images/image1.png" alt="News headline image">
```

However this does not work at all.

//EDIT IMAGE SCREENSHOT:

[imagesFromAsset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEa2F.png)

Please assist

Comment: remove double slashes like this: `file://c:/imagesimage1.png`

Comment: Angular does not have access to local file system. If the only goal is to load the image and replicate the image display issue, place the images in `src/assets/` directory and access them directly without the API call.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the image in assets folder in Angular Project,so that it work once it deploy on server

```
<img class="news-image" src="../../../assets/imgs/image1.png" alt="News headline image"/>
```

or

```
<img class="news-image" src="file://c:/images/image1.png" alt="News headline image"/>
```

And in `component.scss` file set height and width for the image to display as per design.for eg:

```
.news-image{
height:50px;
width:50px;
}
```

Comment: I did as per your 1st suggestion, but apparently it did not work out.

Comment: added broser console.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img class="news-image" src="file://c:/images/image1.png" alt="News headline image">
```

try this